# How to get and edit Android download list?

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager

Can I get and edit the list of files, downloaded with DownloadProvider?

What do I mean? We have an application called Downloads in Android that displays all the downloads made with DownloadProvider. The records it displays are stored in a database somewhere in /data and are not strongly connected with real files. E.g. if I delete a record in Downloads, the file is deleted too, but not vice versa.

So, I want to delete the file in filesystem and delete the record in Downloads application about this file.

Currently I have tried using something like:

```java
DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
query.setFilterByStatus(DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED|
                        DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING|
                        DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING|
                        DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL);
Cursor cur = dm.query(query);
```

and I don't see any ID's in *query* which I could pass to the DownloadManager.remove(long...IDs). Can I do what I want with Android API or the only way to achieve this is to edit the database itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try call

```
mDownloadManager.remove(long... ids)
```

Comment: mDownloadManager.remove(long... ids) requires ids obviously. The problem is that I have no idea how to get them.